# Minority class precision, recall, fscore all become zero with MLP classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall, mlp

I trained my model with MLP classifier which is available on SkLearn.

I split the data using the code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=1)

The X_train length = 9405
Class distribution for y_train = 0: 7562, 1: 1843
X_test length = 4032
class distribution on y_test = 0: 3242, 1: 790
```

The code for the MLP classifier is

```
MLP = MLPClassifier(random_state=1, learning_rate = "constant", learning_rate_init=0.3, momentum = 0.2 )
MLP.fit(X_train, y_train)
R_y_pred = MLP.predict(X_test)
target_names = ['No', 'Yes']
print(classification_report(y_test, R_y_pred, target_names=target_names, zero_division=0))
```

`zero_division= 0` has been included to the classification report because it was suggested from my previous question [Precision, recall, F1 score all have zero value for the minority class in the classification report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75381665/precision-recall-f1-score-all-have-zero-value-for-the-minority-class-in-the-cl?noredirect=1#comment133019629_75381665). The error of my previous question was rectified however the classification report that I got using the above code it seems not correct. The classifier failed to classify **Yes class (minority class)** and classify all classes as **No class**

The classification report looks like

```
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

            No       0.80      1.00      0.89      3242
            Yes       0.00      0.00      0.00       790

       accuracy                           0.80      4032
      macro avg       0.40      0.50      0.45      4032
   weighted avg       0.65      0.80      0.72      4032
```

The problem only occurred for SVM and MLP classifiers. The model trained well with random forest and logistic regression. The dataset is a categorical dataset that is label encoded.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try with passing value zero_division= 1

Comment: That did not work. For `Yes` class precision became 1 if zero_division=1

Comment: I think you got an imbalance classification problem, the Yes class have low training sample what I think. Try to use StratifiedKFold to correctly split your data.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little info to help you, so the following is only a guess. Next time, it might be useful to turn on progress messages by passing `verbose=True` and report those here as well.

The default optimizer is `solver='adam'` and it is not using the `momentum` setting at all (it is only effective for `solver='sgd'` according to the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html)). Also I am wondering how did you come up with `learning_rate_init=0.3`? It is quite high for `adam`, but I think that `adam` is just not the best choice for small datasets like yours. So my guess is that you should try `solver='lbfgs'` or `solver='sgd'`. For the latter you should try to tune the learning rate and momentum parameters.

And if things start to work, I think it might worth to tune the network structure by the parameter `hidden_layer_sizes` as well...